# Include a REST API in Vaadin war app without using Spring boot

Tags: spring, rest, vaadin

I have a Vaadin (v23) app deployed as a war that provides a UI to other wars running in the same Tomcat instance. I now have a need to expose a couple of public endpoints in the Vaadin app via a REST API, but all of the examples I've found assume an app built on Spring-boot, which this isn't. Is there any way of adding a simple, public API to the Vaadin app without having to resort to rebuilding it as a Spring-boot application?

I using tried spring-webmvc with @RestController and overriding startup configurations, but all attempts to navigate to the API are ignored.

Comment: Have you tried something other than Spring? Jersey for example

Comment: JAX-RS is pretty easy to use, see here: https://github.com/TatuLund/cdi-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/cdidemo/rest

Comment: This should be simple to do, just keep in mind to route the rest api endpoints to the correct locations and don't let vaadin grab all url's

Comment: Thanks, I've tried JAX-RS following the example of @TatuLund but Vaadin prevents navigation to it. My Vaadin app has one View extending from AppLayout, and whatever I try, I get an error saying 'could not navigate to ... available routes: <root>'. How do I stop Vaadin from overriding all sub-urls?

Comment: When you have multiple servlets, you need to setup servlet mapping to Vaadin, so that your REST endpoint paths are not intersecting with the Router.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments. I ended up doing it the old-fashioned way, via a static inner class of my MainView:

```
    @WebServlet("/api/*")
    public static class CustomFormServlet extends HttpServlet {
       ...
    }
```

It's an inner class to share some things with MainView. I'm sure there's better ways, but it works and it's only to serve a couple of public endpoints.